# How to do third-party view tracking without cookies?

Tags: web, cookies, privacy

Given a third-party webpage `www.somepage.com` handing out specific URLs to subscribed websites in the format of `www.somepage.com/site/3ir3jsd` - how can I track that a user having an account on `www.somepage.com` has visited one of the subscribed websites without resorting to cookies / localStorage ?

A standard approach would be to store a cookie for `www.somepage.com` and add `www.somepage.com/site/3ir3jsd` via an IFrame. This has several issues as new laws and browser defaults prohibit third-party cookies and local storage to be loaded.

Is there some other mean to achieve this? I see that this is a potential privacy issue and would of course ask for permission to do this and would prefer secure / non-privacy-infringing methods. All major browsers have to be supported which rules out browser extensions too (looking at you Internet Explorer 9-11). Maybe JavaScript? But I don't want the user to have to "login" to my pages service on every subscribed webpage. Storing their session cookie in the first-parties localStorage / cookie is a potential security risk though (which would be needed when using JavaScript + storing their session data).

Another approach I have checked is client certificates but they are poorly supported (read: often unsupported) by mobile browsers and the use-ability of adding them is horribly in most of them too.

Comment: This all sounds slightly dubious anyway, no matter the mechanism. Beyond that, could you not achieve what you need by using redirects, where a visitor ends up at the destination site via a link that hits your site first?

Comment: What is dubious about a service which tracks my activity on participating websites if I opted to create an account there explicitly for this purpose? And no, redirects won't work

Comment: In order for your site be notified when a user visits some other site, you have two choices: they come to you first and are then sent to the other site, or the other site lets you know because it has been configured to do so in advance. You can't do that with cookies when domains don't match, but it looks like they do in this case, in which case what's the problem? A path within your own site is not "another site", and doesn't have any particular legal implications; What you describe sounds similar to groups within facebook.

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding: `www.somepage.com` issues the following url `www.somepage.com/site/3ir3jsd` to another party, e.g. `www.someotherpage.com` - I want a classical external view tracking without cookies that is user dependent as outlined in my question

Comment: So the `www.somepage.com/site/3ir3jsd` link appears somewhere on the `www.someotherpage.com` site, and when a user clicks it, you will know because you will serve that request, and you'll know where it came from from referrer header and link uniqueness? Maintaining user identity across those isn't going to be possible, because your site and their site don't have a common user base, I assume?

Comment: The link `www.somepage.com/site/3ir3jsd` is a technical detail of the iframe variant I have described - using the given URL + a session cookie on `www.somepage.com` I can correlate the logged in user on `www.somepage.com` to the calling site via the provided id (`3ir3jsd`). To elaborate in an implementation agnostic manner: I need a way to correlate the user-session / anonymous-user-id of `www.somepage.com` with another webpage `www.someotherpage.com` on view (not click) via any means besides cookies and localstorage.

Comment: Furthermore `www.someotherpage.com` has no shared user-database / id's with `www.somepage.com` as that would be a privacy hazard and is fundamentally unncessary for the service provided by `www.somepage.com`

Comment: The only way you're going to receive notification when a remote page is viewed is if it contains some resource that you serve - the easiest thing is an image. However, the remote site can't generate a link containing an identifier to the user on *your* site without being told in advance who that is. I'm not seeing a way through this.

Comment: Thanks, this helped :) A pity, I was hoping for WebCrypto + IndexedDB as a client-certificate alternative, but e.g. Safari blocks it on iframes too :/